# What does for good mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean ‘forever’ like the definition in [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/for+good)?

> She told CNBC on a telephone call that she had long been interested in the development of entrepreneurship in Africa and hoped that in working at a big-name bank like JPMorgan she would be able to “redirect the (investment) machine **for good**.” Instead, Horgan Famodu said she ended up feeling as if she had become a “cog in the wheel.”

Source: [CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/05/21/how-maya-horgan-famodu-overcame-rejection-at-the-start-of-her-career.html)

Comment: The actual words themselves are ambiguous here. Pragmatically, ***for good*** here is almost certainly intended as a completely literal usage *(for good **purposes**)*. But with only slight changes to the surrounding context, it could easily be understood in the metaphoric sense ***for good = forever, permanently***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by context it doesn't mean *forever* in this use, but for societal benefit. Here is one of several paragraphs that show that:

> She also created a non-profit initiative alongside her fund, Ingressive for Good, which provides micro-scholarships, technical skills development and talent placement for young people in Africa.